# How to create Microsoft.SshKey using ARM template or SDK using java

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-sdk-for-java

I want to create a service for the creation of a SSH key, as output must retrieve the pem file content.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem can be solved with a simple script.

```
ssh-keygen -t dsa -N "my passphrase" -C "test key" -f mykey
```

This will enable you to automate the process as no prompts will be asked for.
You can add a cat command to return the key if you want.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Apart from this script execution, any other way to generate this SSH key? Like using java code or using ARM template.

Comment: I have a created SSH key on azure cloud, and now I want to create a virtual machine (using ARM) and for that I want to use that created existing key. I dont know public key of that key so what I use in keyData field inside linuxConfiguration

Comment: you can give the keys you just created inside your arm template by,  "adminPublicKey": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Specifies the SSH rsa public key file as a string. Use \"ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 2048\" to generate your SSH key pairs."
      }
    }
  },

Comment: How can I get that SSH rsa public key file, I need that content. kindly help

Comment: dude, just cat ~/. ssh/id_rsa.pub in linux. or whatever path you gave while making the file. (you can give path by " -f ").

Comment: I know that can be done after machine is ready, But my case is I want that public key file (which is created on Azure cloud) while virtual machine creation.